# TypeScript extend a class that modifies the method signature of the base class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

If I have a class

```
class BaseClass<T> {
  save(val: T) {}
}
```

is there a way to extend the base class

```
class ArrayClass<T> extends BaseClass<T[]> {
  save(val: T) {}
}
```

without the compiler complaining?

This works great for what I am trying to achieve. I have most of the logic in the base class but I want a version that works with array and the array manipulation logic is in the derived class. It compiles fine and works perfectly but the compiler complains that I am changing the method signature of that base class from T[] to T in the derived class.

Is there some way I can do this without the compiler complaining?

Comment: `for what I am trying to achieve` can you describe what that is? If i create an `ArrayClass<string>`, what do you want to be passed into `save`: `string[]` or `string`?

Comment: `ArrayClass<User>` creates a store of Users but I am only manipulating one at a time. `save(user)` does the persisting in the base class but the managing the array in the derived class.

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve but without having to manage an instance of the base class. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vbpzem?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fez-array-cache.ts

Comment: At the moment, your type for ArrayClass is saying you want all the methods found in base class, with everything being related to arrays. Then you're overwriting the save function, but trying to make it **not** relate to arrays. I don't know what your desired goal is with this. Is your goal to limit the types that are allowed to only arrays (and it was a mistake to change what type save accepts)? Or is your goal to make the save function operate on a different type than the rest of the inherited methods?

Comment: save calls base.save. I want the class to cache an array of objects but the persist methods on the API only work with a single entity. The StackBlitz above is an example of the pattern using users.

Comment: You can make it work, with a combination of delegation, declaration merging and conditional types: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zadkaf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fez-array-cache.ts. But it is fragile

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks but I am not a fan of this method. I have decided to make a base class that doesn't have the save, update and delete methods and have the single and array classes extend that base.

Comment: Yes that would in fact be better but you were extending a third-party Library. I thought you wanted to reuse their code.

Comment: I own the 3rd party library and made changes to it

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make a child class incompatible with its base class. This is done by design. One of the benefits of subclassing is polymorphism: I should be able to write a function that deals with BaseClass, and that function doesn't need to be concerned whether it got literally a BaseClass, or something that extends from it.

For example, the following function is perfectly legal to write:

```
function doStuff(param: BaseClass<string[]>) {
  param.save(['hello', 'world']);
}
```

But that same function can also legally be called in both of the following ways (assuming `ArrayClass<T>` extends from `BaseClass<T[]>`):

```
doStuff(new BaseClass<string[]>());
doStuff(new ArrayClass<string>());
```

For that to work, both of these implementations must have a save function that accepts an array of strings. So when you violate this, typescript will complain.

Your main options are to either make the save function broader than in the base class (ie, accept both an array of T and an individual T), or to add another function that does the individual save, or to not use inheritence.

Comment: It is not polymorphism I am interested in, I just want to reuse the base class logic in the derived class rather than repeating it.

Comment: `It is not polymorphism I am interested in` You may not be, but typescript is.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
class BaseClass<T> {
  save(val: T) {}
}
```

When we write

```
class NumberArrayClass extends BaseClass<number[]> { }
```

We are passing `number[]` as the type argument for the type parameter `T` declared by `BaseClass<T>`.

Now, to be a subtype of `BaseClass<number[]>`, we must have a `save` method that accepts a `number[]`.

Therefore , the following is an error

```
class NumberArrayClass extends BaseClass<number[]> {
  save(val: number) {}
}
```

because, we have hidden the base member `save`, that in fact does correctly accept a `number[]`.

Remember that there is no overloading in JavaScript. By declaring `save` in the derived `NumberArrayClass`, anyone calling `save` on an instance of it will be calling that new `save`, not the one in `BaseClass`.

If we want to shadow `save` in `NumberArrayClass`, for example to provide additional functionality and or to accept a *broader* range of valid input types, we have to of the accept all valid input types allowed by `BaseClass<number[]>`.

We can do that by adjusting the parameter type of `save` in the derived type.

```
class NumberArrayClass extends BaseClass<number[]> {
   save(val: number | number[]) {
   }
}
```

In your case you can

```
class ArrayClass<T> extends BaseClass<T[]> {      
  save(val: T | T[]) {
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      super.save(val);
    } 
    else {
      super.save([val]);
    }
  }
}
```

*Or you could write a complicated, fragile but interesting monstrosity like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zadkaf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fez-array-cache.ts*

Comment: Which might stop the compiler complaining but would lead the consumers of the class to thing the save method accepts arrays.

Comment: But it must accept an array. You said that it should by saying you extend `BaseClass<T[]>`. If it did not accept an array, it would not be a subtype of `BaseClass<T[]>`. A subtype must be usable as if it were its base.

Comment: I know why the compiler is complaining, I am wondering there is a way to tell it not to. I can do what I want in vanilla JS.

Comment: JavaScript would allow you to _pass_ any value to `save`. You can make both saves take `any`. Based on your other comments however, I think you are perhaps using inheritance for code reuse where another technique would a better fit.

Comment: What is the better technique? If you look at this class https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vbpzem?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fez-array-cache.ts if `EzArrayCache<T, P>` extended `EzCache<T[]>` instead of managing an instance of `EzCache<T[]>` I would have a lot less to manage and just have to overload the save update and delete methods.

Comment: T itself can be a ClassType or an array of ClassType. The base class must be able to handle both with a single Save method. Not too hard to do...

Comment: @JohnPeters that would be straightforward, but he said he does not want it to allow saving arrays or single values, he wants _only_ single values, violating subtyping

Comment: The question then makes no sense whenever an array of ClassType is used.  The Save method must only allow Singleton values while another method allows an array but feeds only Singleton values to Save method.  Simple stuff.